# Windows Server 2008 Standard doesn't show correct amount of memory

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory

After upgrading the amount of memory from 8GB to 24GB my system continues to only 4095 total physical memory (MB) in Windows Task Manager and when using `systeminfo` in CMD. However; when I visit the system properties page the 24.0 GB of RAM is shown.

Here's the dump of `systeminfo`

```
Host Name:                 SERVER
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Standard
OS Version:                6.0.6002 Service Pack 2 Build 6002
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Additional/Backup Domain Controller
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          Windows User
Registered Organization:
Product ID:                55041-702-1711263-76753
Original Install Date:     3/16/2012, 10:27:21 PM
System Boot Time:          1/28/2017, 7:34:42 PM
System Manufacturer:       Dell Inc.
System Model:              PowerEdge R710
System Type:               X86-based PC
Processor(s):              1 Processor(s) Installed.
                           [01]: x64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5 GenuineIntel ~1995 Mhz
BIOS Version:              Dell Inc. 6.4.0, 7/23/2013
Windows Directory:         C:\Windows
System Directory:          C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device:               \Device\HarddiskVolume1
System Locale:             en-us;English (United States)
Input Locale:              en-us;English (United States)
Time Zone:                 (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)
Total Physical Memory:     4,095 MB
Available Physical Memory: 3,072 MB
Page File: Max Size:       8,359 MB
Page File: Available:      7,461 MB
Page File: In Use:         898 MB
Page File Location(s):     C:\pagefile.sys
Domain:                    DOMAIN.com
Logon Server:              \\SERVER
Hotfix(s):                 440 Hotfix(s) Installed.
                           [01]: {AC76BA86-7AD7-0000-2550-7A8C40011010} -
                           [02]: KB971513
                           [03]: KB971512
                           [04]: 944036
                           [05]: KB960362
                           [06]: KB2761494
                           [07]: KB2079403
                           [08]: KB2117917
                           [09]: KB2207559
                           [10]: KB2296011
                           [11]: KB2305420
                           [12]: KB2345886
                           [13]: KB2347290
                           [14]: KB2387149
                           [15]: KB2393802
                           [16]: KB2412687
                           [17]: KB2419640
                           [18]: KB2423089
                           [19]: KB2442962
                           [20]: KB2447568
                           [21]: KB2481109
                           [22]: KB2482017
                           [23]: KB2483185
                           [24]: KB2492386
                           [25]: KB2503665
                           [26]: KB2505189
                           [27]: KB2506212
                           [28]: KB2507618
                           [29]: KB2507938
                           [30]: KB2508429
                           [31]: KB2509553
                           [32]: KB2510531
                           [33]: KB2510581
                           [34]: KB2511455
                           [35]: KB2518866
                           [36]: KB2522422
                           [37]: KB2533623
                           [38]: KB2535512
                           [39]: KB2536275
                           [40]: KB2536276
                           [41]: KB2544521
                           [42]: KB2544521
                           [43]: KB2544893
                           [44]: KB2545698
                           [45]: KB2563227
                           [46]: KB2564958
                           [47]: KB2570947
                           [48]: KB2572075
                           [49]: KB2584146
                           [50]: KB2585542
                           [51]: KB2588516
                           [52]: KB2598479
                           [53]: KB2598845
                           [54]: KB2604094
                           [55]: KB2604105
                           [56]: KB2618451
                           [57]: KB2620704
                           [58]: KB2620712
                           [59]: KB2621146
                           [60]: KB2621440
                           [61]: KB2631813
                           [62]: KB2632503
                           [63]: KB2633171
                           [64]: KB2633874
                           [65]: KB2633952
                           [66]: KB2641653
                           [67]: KB2641690
                           [68]: KB2643719
                           [69]: KB2644615
                           [70]: KB2646524
                           [71]: KB2647170
                           [72]: KB2647516
                           [73]: KB2647518
                           [74]: KB2653956
                           [75]: KB2654428
                           [76]: KB2655992
                           [77]: KB2656362
                           [78]: KB2656374
                           [79]: KB2656409
                           [80]: KB2658846
                           [81]: KB2659262
                           [82]: KB2661254
                           [83]: KB2675157
                           [84]: KB2676562
                           [85]: KB2677070
                           [86]: KB2679255
                           [87]: KB2685939
                           [88]: KB2686833
                           [89]: KB2688338
                           [90]: KB2690533
                           [91]: KB2691442
                           [92]: KB2695962
                           [93]: KB2698365
                           [94]: KB2699988
                           [95]: KB2705219
                           [96]: KB2709162
                           [97]: KB2712808
                           [98]: KB2718523
                           [99]: KB2718704
                           [100]: KB2719985
                           [101]: KB2724197
                           [102]: KB2726535
                           [103]: KB2729453
                           [104]: KB2731847
                           [105]: KB2736233
                           [106]: KB2742601
                           [107]: KB2744842
                           [108]: KB2748349
                           [109]: KB2749655
                           [110]: KB2753842
                           [111]: KB2756822
                           [112]: KB2756919
                           [113]: KB2757638
                           [114]: KB2758857
                           [115]: KB2761226
                           [116]: KB2761465
                           [117]: KB2761465
                           [118]: KB2762895
                           [119]: KB2763674
                           [120]: KB2770660
                           [121]: KB2772930
                           [122]: KB2778344
                           [123]: KB2778930
                           [124]: KB2779030
                           [125]: KB2779562
                           [126]: KB2780091
                           [127]: KB2785220
                           [128]: KB2789646
                           [129]: KB2790655
                           [130]: KB2792100
                           [131]: KB2797052
                           [132]: KB2798162
                           [133]: KB2799329
                           [134]: KB2799494
                           [135]: KB2804580
                           [136]: KB2807986
                           [137]: KB2808679
                           [138]: KB2808735
                           [139]: KB2813170
                           [140]: KB2813345
                           [141]: KB2813430
                           [142]: KB2817183
                           [143]: KB2820197
                           [144]: KB2820917
                           [145]: KB2829361
                           [146]: KB2830290
                           [147]: KB2832412
                           [148]: KB2833947
                           [149]: KB2834886
                           [150]: KB2835361
                           [151]: KB2836945
                           [152]: KB2838727
                           [153]: KB2839229
                           [154]: KB2839894
                           [155]: KB2840149
                           [156]: KB2844287
                           [157]: KB2845690
                           [158]: KB2846071
                           [159]: KB2847311
                           [160]: KB2849470
                           [161]: KB2850851
                           [162]: KB2853587
                           [163]: KB2855844
                           [164]: KB2859537
                           [165]: KB2861190
                           [166]: KB2861855
                           [167]: KB2862152
                           [168]: KB2862330
                           [169]: KB2862335
                           [170]: KB2862772
                           [171]: KB2862966
                           [172]: KB2862973
                           [173]: KB2863058
                           [174]: KB2863253
                           [175]: KB2864058
                           [176]: KB2864063
                           [177]: KB2864202
                           [178]: KB2868038
                           [179]: KB2868116
                           [180]: KB2868623
                           [181]: KB2868626
                           [182]: KB2876284
                           [183]: KB2876331
                           [184]: KB2879017
                           [185]: KB2883150
                           [186]: KB2884256
                           [187]: KB2887069
                           [188]: KB2888505
                           [189]: KB2891804
                           [190]: KB2892075
                           [191]: KB2893294
                           [192]: KB2893984
                           [193]: KB2894847
                           [194]: KB2898785
                           [195]: KB2898858
                           [196]: KB2900986
                           [197]: KB2901113
                           [198]: KB2901674
                           [199]: KB2904266
                           [200]: KB2909210
                           [201]: KB2909921
                           [202]: KB2911502
                           [203]: KB2916036
                           [204]: KB2918614
                           [205]: KB2922229
                           [206]: KB2923392
                           [207]: KB2925418
                           [208]: KB2926765
                           [209]: KB2929733
                           [210]: KB2930275
                           [211]: KB2931354
                           [212]: KB2936068
                           [213]: KB2937608
                           [214]: KB2939576
                           [215]: KB2943344
                           [216]: KB2953522
                           [217]: KB2957189
                           [218]: KB2957503
                           [219]: KB2957509
                           [220]: KB2957689
                           [221]: KB2961072
                           [222]: KB2962872
                           [223]: KB2968292
                           [224]: KB2972098
                           [225]: KB2973201
                           [226]: KB2974268
                           [227]: KB2974269
                           [228]: KB2976627
                           [229]: KB2976897
                           [230]: KB2977629
                           [231]: KB2978116
                           [232]: KB2979568
                           [233]: KB2981580
                           [234]: KB2987107
                           [235]: KB2991963
                           [236]: KB2992611
                           [237]: KB2993651
                           [238]: KB2993958
                           [239]: KB2998579
                           [240]: KB2999226
                           [241]: KB3000061
                           [242]: KB3000483
                           [243]: KB3000869
                           [244]: KB
Network Card(s):           6 NIC(s) Installed.
                           [01]: Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (NDIS VBD Client)
                                 Connection Name: Local Area Connection
                                 DHCP Enabled:    No
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: 10.0.0.76
                                 [02]: fe80::8407:17fc:99c4:42fb
                           [02]: Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (NDIS VBD Client)
                                 Connection Name: Local Area Connection 2
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [03]: Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (NDIS VBD Client)
                                 Connection Name: Local Area Connection 3
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [04]: Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (NDIS VBD Client)
                                 Connection Name: Local Area Connection 4
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [05]: Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (NDIS VBD Client)
                                 Connection Name: Local Area Connection 5
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
                           [06]: Broadcom BCM5709C NetXtreme II GigE (NDIS VBD Client)
                                 Connection Name: Local Area Connection 6
                                 Status:          Media disconnected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this line from systeminfo:

> System Type:               X86-based PC

You are running a 32 bit OS.

The output on my 64bit Windows 10 is:

> System Type:               x64-based PC

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2008 you are limited to 4GB.

You should upgrade to 64bit.

Comment: Correct, however above the table reads

Physical Memory Limits: Windows Server 2008

The following table specifies the limits on physical memory for Windows Server 2008. **Limits greater than 4 GB for 32-bit Windows assume that PAE is enabled.**

Comment: I think that is referring to the Enterprise and the Datacenter version. You have the Standard verison, which is limited to 4GB.

Comment: @gh0st 32-bit Server 2008 Standard is limited to 4GB; it is 64-bit Server 2008 Standard that can use up to 32GB of RAM. It's quite bizarre that this got installed as a 32-bit OS in the first place; there was no good reason to do that even back in 2012, certainly not for a domain controller.

Comment: So PAE on Windows 2008 Server Standard does nothing?

Comment: It seems you can force it to be enabled, but it won't do anything since Microsoft limited the standard edition to 4GB.